# Ubuntu filesystem buffers/cache always empty

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, cache, openvz

I have a virtual server with ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and plesk (preinstalled by hosting company).
Now i have seen that the buffers/cache are always empty.
Current uptime is 22 days. free and htop shows the same values.

```
root@server:/root# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096        540       3555          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:        540       3555
Swap:         4096          0       4096
```

mount info:

```
root@server:/root# mount
/dev/vzfs on / type reiserfs (rw,usrquota,grpquota)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime)
```

I have searched stackexchange/google but found nothing.
How can I enable filecache or is this not possible cause of vzfs and all is good?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caching is done by the OpenVZ host and is shared between all containers on the node. OpenVZ is not a real virtual environment. It runs on the host node's kernel, which is what performs disk caching. You can think of it more as an isolated chroot.